# Highlight without comments in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, highlighting, comments

How to highlight text in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC without adding any comment? I have tried many was but couldn't figure out anything.

Comment: Please EDIT your comment to tell us specifically what you have tried. If you've tried "many" we don't know what you've tried, and we don't wish to waste time suggesting things that you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uncheck this option from the commenting section preferences:

**Copy selected text into highlights**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's only this checkbox that needs to be set properly but by making mine look largely like the one in this screenshot from the Adobe forums, I was able to also accomplish the end result. https://community.adobe.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/48772iCD091ED987A19B83/image-size/original?v=v2&px=-1